# Android app freezes after some seconds of successful audio recording and processing

Tags: android, multithreading, audio

my app is freezing after about 10 seconds of expected behavior and I struggle to pinpoint the cause.

- are there memory issues?
- is there a problem with the audio buffer?

The app is supposed to sample audio from the mic, process it to detect the peak frequency and to visualize the result on the screen. I have the MainActivity in which a thread is defined to update the view. I have two other threads implemented separately, one for recording the audio through the AudioRecord class, one for processing the audio signal and to detect the peak frequency. The recording and processing seems to work and to yield the expected results. However, after some time (the exact time varies form one run to the next) the app will freeze. The log then shows repeated messages of

> W/art: Suspending all threads took: x.xxxms
>
> I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed ...

The number of objects removed by GC can be quite high (one case: 62119(3MB)) and I am wondering where I create this amount of objects and how to avoid it? I suspect that there is a problem with the audio buffer, but did not know how best to diagnose this.

Here the relevant code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "StringTuner";

    VerticalLineDrawingView drawView;       // view to draw frequency indicator
    TextView textView;                      // view for text output

    private AudioRecorderThread recorder;   // thread for recording audio
    private ProcessingThread processor;     // thread for processing audio signal
    private Thread viewUpdater;             // thread for updating views

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        recorder.releaseAudioRecord();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Creating the main activity");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawView = (VerticalLineDrawingView) this.findViewById(R.id.drawView_NoteIndicator);
        textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView_TextOutput);


        Log.d(TAG, "Setting up AudioRecord and processing thread");
        recorder = new AudioRecorderThread();
        recorder.start();

        processor = new ProcessingThread(recorder);
        processor.start();

        // thread for updating view
        if (viewUpdater == null){
            viewUpdater = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                try {
                    while (recorder != null && processor != null) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                            if (processor != null){
                                textView.setText(String.valueOf(processor.getPeakFrequency()) + " Hz\n" + processor.getProcessingTime() + " ms");
                                drawView.reposition((int) (processor.getPosition() * drawView.getViewWidth()));
                            }
                            }
                        });
                        sleep(1);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    viewUpdater = null;
                }
                }
            };
            viewUpdater.start();
        }

    }

}
```

AudioRecorderThread.java

```
public class AudioRecorderThread extends Thread {

    private AudioRecord audioRecord;
    private boolean isRecording;
    private int nSample;
    private int frameByteSize;
    private byte[] frame;
    private byte[] buffer;

    public AudioRecorderThread(){

        int channel     = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;          // channel configuration
        int encoding    = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       // audio encoding
        int fS          = getMinimumSampleRate();               // sample rate [Hz]

        // get minimum buffer size for AudioRecord session
        int minBuffer   = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(fS, channel, encoding);

        int src         = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;        // audio source

        // instantiate AudioRecord session
        audioRecord     = new AudioRecord(src, fS, channel, encoding, minBuffer);
        if (audioRecord.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("AudioRecord session could not be initialized.");
        }

        nSample     = getNextPowerOf2(fS);                  // frequency resolution below 1 Hz
        frameByteSize   = 2 * nSample;                          // 16bit -> 1 frame = 2* sample size
        frame = new byte[frameByteSize];

        buffer          = new byte[frameByteSize];              // buffer for reading data

    }

    public AudioRecord getAudioRecord(){
        return audioRecord;
    }

    public boolean isRecording(){
        return this.isAlive() && isRecording;
    }

    public void startRecording(){
        try{
            audioRecord.startRecording();
            isRecording = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording(){
        try{
            audioRecord.stop();
            isRecording = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void releaseAudioRecord(){
        try{
            audioRecord.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] getFrame(){
        audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, 800);                     // one sample = 2 bytes (16 bits)
        System.arraycopy(frame,800,frame,0,800);
        System.arraycopy(buffer,0,frame,frameByteSize-800,800);
        return frame;
    }

    public int getFrameByteSize(){
        return frameByteSize;
    }

    public double getFrequencySteps(){
        return ((double) audioRecord.getSampleRate()) / ((double) nSample);
    }

    public void run() {
        startRecording();

        // fill buffer
        audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, frameByteSize);             // read 1 frame of data into buffer
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, frame, 0, frameByteSize);

    }
}
```

ProcessingThread.java

```
public class ProcessingThread extends Thread{

    private AudioRecorderThread recorder;
    private volatile Thread _thread;
    private int bytesPerSample;

    private long t_process;
    private double f_peak;
    private double position;

    private double[] stringFrequenciesLog = new double[] {Math.log(82.4), Math.log(110), Math.log(146.8), Math.log(196), Math.log(246.9), Math.log(329.6)};
    private double[] stringPositions = new double[] {2.0/9.0, 3.0/9.0, 4.0/9.0, 5.0/9.0, 6.0/9.0, 7.0/9.0};

    public ProcessingThread(AudioRecorderThread recorder){

        this.recorder = recorder;
        AudioRecord audioRecord = recorder.getAudioRecord();

        if (audioRecord.getAudioFormat() == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT){
            bytesPerSample = 2;
        }
        else if (audioRecord.getAudioFormat() == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT){
            bytesPerSample = 1;
        }

    }

    public void start() {
        _thread = new Thread(this);
        _thread.start();
    }

    public void stopDetection(){
        _thread = null;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            double maxValue;
            long t0;
            byte[] frame;
            short[] sample = new short[recorder.getFrameByteSize()/2];
            double[] sampleAsDouble = new double[sample.length];
            double[] magnitudes;
            FastFourierTransform fft = new com.dsp.FastFourierTransform();

            Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
            while (_thread == thisThread) {

                t0 = System.nanoTime();

                // read recorded audio data
                frame = recorder.getFrame();

                // processing
                if (frame != null) {
                    // sound detected
                    sample = decodeSample(frame);

                    for (int j=0;j<sample.length;j++) {
                        sampleAsDouble[j] = (double)sample[j];
                    }

                    // todo: bandpass filter the audio signal

                    // todo: fft the audio signal
                    magnitudes = fft.getMagnitudes(sampleAsDouble);

                    // todo: identify peak frequency
                    maxValue = magnitudes[0];
                    f_peak   = 0.0;
                    for (int i=1; i<magnitudes.length; i++) {
                        if (magnitudes[i]>maxValue) {
                            maxValue = magnitudes[i];
                            f_peak = (double) i * recorder.getFrequencySteps();
                        }
                    }

                    frequency2position(f_peak);

                    t_process = System.nanoTime() - t0;

                }
                else{
                    // no sound detected
                    f_peak = -1;
                    position = -5;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private short[] decodeSample(byte[] buffer) {

        short[] sample;

        if (bytesPerSample==2) {

            sample = new short[buffer.length/2];

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 2) {
                sample[i/2] = (short) ((buffer[i]) | buffer[i + 1] << 8);
            }

        } else {

            sample = new short[buffer.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                sample[i] = (short) buffer[i];
            }

        }

        return sample;

    }

    private void frequency2position(double f){

        // check f is in valid frequency range
        double f_min = 30;
        double f_max = 3000;

        if (f<f_min) {
            position = -1;
            return;
        }

        if (f>f_max) {
            position = -2;
            return;
        }

        double f_log = Math.log(f);

        // find closest string frequency
        int closestIndex = 0;
        double distance = Math.abs(f_log - stringFrequenciesLog[closestIndex]);
        while ((closestIndex < stringFrequenciesLog.length-1) && (Math.abs(f_log - stringFrequenciesLog[closestIndex+1])) < distance) {
            distance = Math.abs(f_log - stringFrequenciesLog[closestIndex+1]);
            closestIndex++;
        }

        double alpha = f_log/stringFrequenciesLog[closestIndex];
        position = alpha * stringPositions[closestIndex];

        if (position<0) {
            position = -3;
            return;
        }

        if (position>1) {
            position = -4;
        }

    }

    public double getPosition(){
        return position;
    }

    public double getPeakFrequency(){
        return f_peak;
    }

    public long getProcessingTime(){
        return t_process/1000000; // in ms
    }

}
```

VerticalLineDrawingView.java

```
public class VerticalLineDrawingView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    private int position = -1;
    private int screenHeight = 0;
    private int screenWidth = 0;

    private Paint mLinePaint = new Paint();

    public VerticalLineDrawingView(final Context ct) {
        super(ct);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalLineDrawingView(final Context ct, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ct, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalLineDrawingView(final Context ct, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(ct, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mLinePaint.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.greenPrimary, null));
        mLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canv) {
        if (position>0) {
            canv.drawLine(position, 0, position, screenHeight, mLinePaint);
            getLayout().draw(canv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        screenHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        screenWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        screenWidth = w;
        screenHeight = h;
    }

    public void reposition(int newpos) {
        position   = newpos;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getViewWidth() {
        return screenWidth;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are doing to many operation on mainthread that's why it is hanging, to avoid this use Asynctask.